# Google Forms Phone Number Format

Tags: validation, google-forms, phone-number

When adding a new phone number in Google contacts, there is a flag selection box in front of the number to easily select the country code.

Is it possible to implement a phone number field for Google Forms with the same logic? That is, choosing the country code from the list and writing just the phone number on the side.

Thanks

Comment: No, as of now there is no way you can do it with Google Form.